# Как передать следующему элементу массива сумму предыдущего и определенного числа

Tags: c#, массивы

[image: Пример кода]

Цель: передать каждому следующему элементу массива сумму предыдущего и числа 5.

Например: `arr[0] = 2; arr[1] = arr[0] + 5; arr[2] = arr[1] + 5;` и так далее.

Как сделать это простым способом?

Comment: Вынесите `arr[0] = 2;` перед циклом.

Comment: Не надо скриншотов кода. Код _всегда_ публикуйте как текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, под "предыдущим" подразумевается изначальное значение элемента массива, ещё не изменённое.

Нужно проходить по массиву от конца к началу:

```
var arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arr));

for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 5;
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arr));
```

Тогда в нашем распоряжении будет предыдущее чистое значение.